# ROS_PACKAGE_PATH doesn't save

Tags: ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody!

I've a problem with ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.
First I tried to ad the path to my workspace with this command line
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
After I check the PATH
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
And It's OK :
/home/andrei/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks

BUT

But there no more the path to recently added directory when I close the terminal or I open a new terminal Tab.

How do you think, where is my mistake?

Thank you!!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214148/ros_package_path-doesn%27t-save/) by [Andrei](https://answers.ros.org/users/23268/andrei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is completely normal behaviour. Either resource it every time or add the source... line to your ~/.bashrc, so it is done automatically.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrei](https://answers.ros.org/users/23268/andrei/) on 2015-07-20**:
Thank you for your help!

**Comment by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on 2015-07-20**:
Consider writing a comment instead of a whole answer saying "thank you". Also please refer to the tutorials and more specific http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment#Managing_Your_Environment